# Making wrapper objects compatible with @singledispatch?

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic-typing, generic-function, single-dispatch

Say I have a class like this:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.__obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        logger.debug('Accessing %s', name)
        return getattr(self.__obj, name)
```

Elsewhere in the codebase are [generic functions using the @singledispatch decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).  I'd like for "wrapped" instances to act like they were never wrapped.  So for example, `pprint(Wrapper({}))` will operate like `pprint({})`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm, I can tell this will be pretty difficult because stdlib singledispatch works on the type. No matter how transparent you can make the wrapper, I don't know a way to lie about its type.